# Multinomial Coefficient Divisibility Relation

Tags: number-theory

I've had a few attempts now at coming up with a rigorous proof for the divisibility of $n!$ by the product of factorials in  the $k^{th}$ multinomial coefficient in $m$ variables, the statement below is what I "feel" as if I should be stating, but there seem to be obvious steps and assertions missing at least until I consider it to be vigorous, let alone everyone else.

The combined conditions of:

1) these factorials in the product being equal to the exponents of the variable product in the $k^{th}$ monomial (or individual term in the multinomial expansion if you like)

2) Their values being positive integers between 0 and $n$

3) The sum of the arguments of the factorials must be equal to $n$.

Seem to be the best justification I can think of at this point as to why we are always guaranteed the assurance of the divisibility relation being true, so I have stated this as follows:
$$\sum _{j=1}^{m}\alpha_{{k,\,j}}=n\, \land \,0\leq \alpha_{{k,\,j}}\leq n \Rightarrow \prod _{j=1}^{m}\alpha_{{k,j}}!\,\, | \,n!$$

Edit: Kummer's Theorem may be generalized to apply to the multinomial coefficients and prove this divisibility relation. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've already noticed that you can prove this by looking at the powers of primes dividing the factorials (essentially your generalization of Kummer's theorem), but if you prefer a combinatorial approach,

$$\frac{n!}{\prod_{j=1}^{m}\alpha_{j}!}$$

(for $\alpha_j$ which sum to $n$) counts the number of different permutations of $\alpha_1$ 1's, $\alpha_2$ 2's, ..., $\alpha_m$ m's. This is because there are $n!$ ways to arrange all $n$ symbols, but this overcounts by a factor of $\prod \alpha_j!$, since there are $\alpha_j!$ ways to rearrange the set of $\alpha_j$ $j$s.